# Is it possible to configure Log Analytics to capture information from Azure SQL Server automatic backups?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to extract information like (Date, time, if it was successful or not) from the automatic PITR backups of Azure SQL Server, does anyone have any experience about?

I tried ingesting through log analytics, but I didn't get exactly what I needed.

Comment: can you share code what you that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the backup of your Database directly from Azure Portal like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can also query the system tables of backup by logging into the Azure SQL DB with SSMS like below:-

In the Views > System Views > Select > **[sys].[dm_database_backups]** > And query the database to get backup information, Refer below:-

[image]

Its not possible to retrieve the Azure SQL Server PTIR logs after ingesting them to Log analytics workspace. I tried to ingest logs from Azure SQL Server by enabling Azure SQL Server auditing and sending the logs to Log analytics workspace like below:-

Enabled Audit logs for Azure SQL server:-

[image]

Received the logs in my Log analytics workspace but the log table did not have any category with Backup Refer below:-

[image]

I tried to send the logs of Azure SQL backup DB to log analytics via Azure Backed up database Diagnostic settings but the metric tables did not include backup as the Backup is Azure SQL Server level task for DB’s refer below:-

[image]

[Configure streaming export of metrics and resource logs - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/metrics-diagnostic-telemetry-logging-streaming-export-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal)

Additionally you can make use of below Powershell commands to get the Azure SQL backup information:-

```
Get-AzSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -ServerName "sql-servername" -DatabaseName "sqldbname"
```

```
Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -ServerName "sqlservername" -DatabaseName "sqldbname"
```

Output:-

[image]

You can call the REST API below to get the List the LTR details of Azure SQL Server :-

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/{locationName}/longTermRetentionServers/{longTermRetentionServerName}/longTermRetentionDatabases/{longTermRetentionDatabaseName}/longTermRetentionBackups?api-version=2022-05-01-preview
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation I also did the same tests and could not get the list of backup logs with process details. I need backup logs for an internal audit process i will try talk with Microsoft. Thank you!